# Example of a differentiable function that has a Fourier series that diverges

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

It is known that for any null set $N\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there is a continuous periodic function that has a Fourier series that diverges at all point of $N$.

In particular, there are continuous functions with divergent Fourier series at some point.

Is it true for differentiable functions?

Comment: By Dini criterion, the Fourier series converges at any point of differentiability of a function